# Acces Excel Sheet from Button a Ribbon

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, ribbon, excel-addins

Ok, so I got my **main AddIn** which auto generated (*Attachment 1*)
and there is my **Ribbon** (*Attachment 2*) and I want to access the currently active excel sheet from that ribbon. But `System.Windows.Forms.Application` does not contain a definition for `ActiveSheet`.

#### Attachment 1:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }
    public void doStuff()
    {
       
    }
    
    #endregion



}
}
```

Attachement 2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
public partial class Ribbon1
{
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
        Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet);
        Excel.Range firstRow = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1");
        firstRow.EntireRow.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
        Excel.Range newFirstRow = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1");
        newFirstRow.Value2 = "This text was added by using code";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to obtain the [`IRibbonControl.Context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribboncontrol.context.aspx) from the [`RibbonControlEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribboncontroleventargs.aspx) parameter. This context represents the [`Excel.Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.window.aspx). Then you can access the active [`Window.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.window.application.aspx) property.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Window window = e.Control.Context;
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
    Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)window.Application.ActiveSheet);
    Excel.Range firstRow = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1");
    firstRow.EntireRow.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
    Excel.Range newFirstRow = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1");
    newFirstRow.Value2 = "This text was added by using code";
}
```

Comment: Why not `window.ActiveSheet` instead of `window.Application.ActiveSheet`?

Answer (score 10):

If this is a VSTO Excel Add-In, maybe you should use:

```
   Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
```

Regards, Jörg